# Android Scrollable Soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

[image]

How to make soft keyboard horizontally scrollable?

ScrollView does not work.

Comment: Keyboard layout doesn't allow scroll view. You can do this by virtual keyboard instead if you need this only for your application.